# Как составить регулярное выражение для проверки вхождения числа в определенный диапазон?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно задать регулярное выражение для диапазона чисел от 1 до 32. Если число больше или меньше нужно возвращать false.

Comment: в чем проблема? :)

Comment: @Grundy, тут видимо хотят готовый ответ получить, даже не попробовав решить задачу )

Comment: Таких вопросов куча. Воспользуйтесь сниппетом из указанного вопроса, чтобы сгенерировать любой диапазон, а не 1...32

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для проверки того, что значение находится в определенном диапазоне лучше привести его к числу и затем проверить.

```
var v = parseInt(value);
if(v>=1 && v=<32) 
    return true;
return false;
```

Если очень хочется использовать регулярное выражение, можно использовать следующее

```
/^(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32)$/
```

Comment: Зачем так? `/^([1-2]?[\d]|3[0-2])$/` :)

Comment: @Other, у вас 0 подходит, а это неверно.

Comment: @Other, потому что самый простой вариант :-) можешь добавить ответ со своим вариантом

Comment: @VenZell, хм, действительно, так, наверное: `^([1-9]|[1-2][\d]|3[0-2])$`

Comment: @VenZell, о как, совпало, гении мыслят одинаково? У Вас не копировал.

Comment: @Other, регулярка простая, ничего удивительного :)

Comment: @VenZell, приятней думать что ты гений, а не то, что это задача из детсада :)

Comment: Как и [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522335/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4#comment644499_522351), не понял, почему в шаблоне используются границы *строки*, а не *«слова»*.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, в данном случае не принципиально, так как нет дополнительных ограничений на то, что в строке могут быть еще символы, кроме того данное выражение так же может работать на многострочном тексте

Comment: Поставлю минус за регулярку

Comment: @ReinRaus, она разве не работает? :)

Comment: Работает, но это ужасно :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, :-D.

Answer (score 4):

```
/^([1-9]|[1-2][\d]|3[0-2])$/
```

`[1-9]` - числа от 1 до 9
`|` - ИЛИ
`[1-2][\d]` - числа от 10 до 29
`|` - ИЛИ
`3[0-2]` - числа от 30 до 32

#### Альтернативный вариант

```
/^([1-2]?[1-9]|[1-3][0-2])$/
```

`[1-2]?[1-9]` - числа от 1 до 9, числа от 11 до 19, числа от 21 до 29
`|` - ИЛИ
`[1-3][0-2]` - числа от 10 до 12, числа от 20 до 22, числа от 30 до 32

Comment: а можно ли сократить еще?

Comment: @Grundy, попробую и обновлю ответ

Comment: @Grundy, а куда тут сократишь?

Comment: Не найдётся же ничего, если в строке помимо чисел ещё что-то содержится, [**демонстрация**](https://regex101.com/r/kN7sV2/3).

И зачем метасимвол `\d` оборачивать в скобки? 

Мой пример: `\b([1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-2])\b` — [**демонстрация**](https://regex101.com/r/kN7sV2/2).

Comment: можете еще дефис между 1 и 2 убрать - еще - символ :)

Comment: @splash58, одна фигня. Как и убрать `[]`. Если что-то важно убрать можно - это другой, куда более интересный вопрос.

Comment: @Grundy, с сокращением кроме способов, описанных выше, не выходит. Только альтернативный вариант вышло накатать.

Answer (score -1):

32 это же степень двойки, можно битами проверять:

```
32  100000
31  011111
30  011110
..
 2  000010
 1  000001
```

Число минус 1 должно быть от 0 до 31: от `00000` до `11111`.

```
if( ((x - 1) & 0x1F) === (x - 1)) {
  // OK
} else {
  // NOT OK
}
```

Comment: 32 это ж строка

Comment: @Grundy как только видит `(x - 1)`, внезапно становится числом

Comment: логично.... :-)